# User Edit Permissions in Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to decide if Freeform (or Freeform Pro) is a good fit for what I need to do and wondering a couple things about forms I can set up for member us.

For front end edits, can users edit entries that have been approved or can they only view pending? I want to set it up so they can edit entries that have been rejected or are still pending but not once they have been published.

Also can you allow users to edit an existing entry but as pending? Such as submitting edits or extra information on an entry and if approved, that information appears on that particular entry. If allowed is this a feature on free, pro or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would set up your form to have a status of "pending" so that the Freeform entry has a status of "pending".

Then, for a user to be able to edit these "pending" form entries, use `{exp:freeform:entries}` to first retrieve the entries, then display the Freeform Edit form using `{exp:freeform:edit}` (Note: this tag is a Freeform Pro feature only). For example:

```
{exp:freeform:entries status="pending" /* your other parameters here */}
    {exp:freeform:edit 
         form_id="1" 
         entry_id="{freeform:entry_id}"
         restrict_edit_to_author="no"
         allow_status_edit="yes"}

      // Your form containing a field for changing the status, 
      // if status="" is not defined/hard-coded as a parameter:
      <select name="status" id="status">
         <option value="">Select:</option>
         {freeform:statuses status="not closed|testing"}
            <option value="{status_name}"
         {if freeform:edit_data:status == "{status_name}"}
            selected="selected"
         {/if}>
            {status_label}
            </option>
         {/freeform:statuses}
      </select>

    {/exp:freeform:edit}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Your second question is answered with the above: you could use status="pending" in `{exp:freeform:edit}` to set entries to be "pending", or use a form field to allow the user to change (or not) the entry's status. Again, this is a Freeform Pro feature.

Comment: I think my second question was improperly worded. I meant if they submit a form about an already existing entry in a channel such as correcting an article or adding missing text. Can you have their newly added info update the already existing published entry but not before approval by the admin.

Comment: Like creating an updated "draft" of a pre-existing Freeform entry, which then updates the official entry after admin approval? Unfortunately Freeform doesn't have such a feature. Maybe you can somehow use a separate form and entries to store such "drafts", then later have an admin update the "non-draft" entries with that information. A combination of {exp:freeform:entries} and {exp:freeform:edit}, similar to the above, could be used.

Comment: Right so just to clarify, I would still be having them being entered as drafts and if they are a duplicate, instead of approving I would just have to copy and paste the information into the previous entry. Makes sense.